# Use VBA Code to change folder names based on excel List Column

Tags: excel, vba, performance, automation, office365

I have folders showing up as the following [Folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KYyN.png)

I have the path of these folders in Cell B1 and the Name I need to change the folders in Column A. I do not have that much VBA experience and cannot get how to get folders name to change to the listing on the listing I have on Column A.
Note: I'm only showing four tasks in the image, but I have over 50 for multiple folders and I have the name of what the file should be in excel sheets, which is why I need this to automate.
I wouldn't even care if i could at least get the parentheses to be replaced by the names I have on Column A of my excel sheet.

Thanks for any help!!
[image: IMAGE HERE]

Comment: This type of task is pretty easily handled without coding using utilities like Microsoft's [`PowerRename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/powerrename) utility, and this may be a approach for you than using VBA. If that does not work for you, an image of your worksheet may help me or others to get you through the task

Comment: See for example: https://www.howtoexcel.org/how-to-create-delete-and-rename-folders-from-a-list/

Comment: @TaylorRaine I added the image above. So, for example: I need Task 1 to be either: "Task 1 (Summer Projects)" or just "Summer Projects". I hope this helps in what I'm trying to do. I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at this solution:

```
Sub RenameFolders()
    
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    
    Dim newFolderName As String
    Dim oldFolderName As String
    
    Dim newFolderRange As Range
    
    For Each newFolderRange In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
        oldFolderName = newFolderRange.Offset(0, 1).Value
        newFolderName = GetParentPath(oldFolderName) & newFolderRange.Value
        Name oldFolderName As newFolderName
    Next newFolderRange

End Sub

Function GetParentPath(ByVal path As String)
    
    path = StrReverse(path)
    GetParentPath = StrReverse(Mid(path, InStr(1, path, "\")))

End Function
```

Comment: There is no need to do use two `StrReverse` with `Instr` here - you can just use `InStrRev` instead

Comment: @TaylorRaine how would I do with PowerRename using the list of names I already have? I have never used this feature before and the link you gave me...I don't quite see how I can do that

Answer (score 0):

## Using [PowerRename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/powerrename) + VBA

To avoid having to handle RegEx or string matching in VBA, we can handle that quickly using PowerRename with by matching the regular expression `Task (\d+) .*` and replacing with the captured task number using `$1`, as shown below

[image: PowerRename]

This leaves us with a *much* simpler renaming task that can be handled with a single line line of VBA. Specifically, if you drop the path to the directory (including the terminal `\`) into cell `C1` then you can use the immediate window command

```vb
For Row=1 To [CountA(A:A)]:Name [C1]&Row As [C1]&Cells(Row,1):Next
```

to rename the files to your existing list. You can access the immediate window with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. The end result should look something like the below:

[image: Renaming]

Note that I am using the command

```vb
For Each fld in CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder([C1]).SubFolders: ?fld.Name: Next
```

to verify the change in the image above